# Angular JS multi level routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have an application as following structure

```
Index.html
```

which has `app.js` with all routing and `ng-view` is added inside `index.html`

I have another template which am loding on successive login over this ng-view is `home.html`

can i have a `ng-view` inside the `home.html`as well ? and load to that `ng-view` when I click on any menus inside link of home page ?

I am adding my routing details bellow

.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/login', {
        controller: 'LoginController',
        templateUrl: 'modules/authentication/views/login.html'
    })

    .when('/home', {
        controller: 'HomeController',
        templateUrl: 'modules/home/views/home.html'
    })

    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login' });
}])
```

can I add a new routing and load a tempale and controler inside `home.html` in place of `index.html` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want a ng-view inside a ng-view. I think you cannot do that. But the solution would be use the parameter reloadOnSearch which you can set as false, so everytime you reload the page changing it's route it will not reload the previously loaded html structure.

```
.when('/home', {
    controller: 'HomeController',
    templateUrl: 'modules/home/views/home.html',
    reloadOnSearch: false
})
```

But to make it work this way you have to type in the fixed html structure in every page you want. A way of doing that is adding includes to your home page and set the view pages by scope variables.

```
<!--home.html-->
<!--define your structure here-->

<!--includes that will load the desired pages-->
<div>
  <div ng-include="'./indexGeneral.html'"  ng-if="Page == 'general'"></div>
  <div ng-include="'./indexContacts.html'" ng-if="Page == 'contacts'"></div>
  <div ng-include="'./indexVehicles.html'" ng-if="Page == 'vehicles'"></div>
</div>
```